# find $f(g(x))$ given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: calculus

let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1  & x<\frac 12 \\
-\frac12, & \text{if} -\frac12\leq x<0 \\
0  & \text{x=0}\\
1  & \text{x>0}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x)= 1+x-[x],$$ where $[x]$ denoted largest integer not exceeding $x$. then what is $f(g(x))$?

1. $ -1$
2. $-\frac{1}2$
3. $0$
4. $1$

my doubt: $g(x)$ can be written as $1-\{x\}$ where $\{x\}$ is fractional part of $x$. Since range of $g(x)$ is $(0,1)$ so $f(g(x))=1$. So I want to confirm my answer i get option 4 is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: As you are checking a constant candidate, just eval it at some points of your choice, like $x = 0$.

Comment: $g(x) = 1 + (x - [x]) = 1 + \{x\}$, using your notation.

Comment: @singularity, how can $1$ *plus* a positive quantity give you something *less than* $1$?

Answer (score 2):

Actually $g(x)$ is $1+\{x\}$, not $1-\{x\}$, but the conclusion is basically the same:  $g(x)\ge1\gt0$ for all $x$, so $f(g(x))=1$.